# Вывод double в файл в java

Tags: java, файлы, строки, io, double

Мне надо выводить числа типа `double` в файл, а также читать их оттуда. Однако при попытке чтения выведенных чисел у меня возникает ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

в этом фрагменте:

```
public HiddenNeuron(int cnt, double[] oxses) {
    this.w = new double[cnt];
    this.x = new double[cnt];
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        this.x[i] = oxses[i];
        this.w[i] = whi.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

в строке `this.w[i] = oxses[i];`

В файл все числа выводятся через точку, т.е. `1.2345`, но если заменить её на запятую (`1,2345`), программа работает без ошибок. Запись в файл происходит при помощи `PrintWriter(FileWriter)`:

```
PrintWriter pi = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(wf));
ph.write(String.valueOf(hilayer[i].w[j]));
```

Пытался через `String.valueOf()` и через `double + ""` переводить в `String`, но всегда выводит через точку.

Comment: Ну и что вам мешает читать число менять точку на запятую или на оборот и записывать в переменную?

Comment: я не знаю как это делать,приходится самому заходить в файл и менять вручную точки на запятые

Comment: Что то я не совсем понимаю,куда вы пишете. Писатель объявлен pi, а запись в ph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно установить настройки локали для сканнера:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
sc.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

http://www.cyberforum.ru/java-j2se/thread783127.html#post4115840

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: спасибо, сработало!